# Is overriding css risk free?

Tags: css, branding

I work as an administrator and have been asked to change the look of a few sites. We have sharepoint 2013 on-premise. Are there any risks of override the existing CSS? Is there something I should definitely avoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On-prem, that will be risk free as the DOM won't change for that product. It becomes a larger issue in SharePoint Online where the DOM can change at any time as Microsoft updates the product.

Comment: Glad to hear! Can I point to a CSS file through a snippet, or could it cause a problem?

Comment: You can do that.

Answer (score 0):

[SharePoint Color Palette Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182) is I guess one of the best and simpler tools for branding / changing CSS for the site.
You can [refer](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000235451-how-to-change-sharepoint-color-palette-and-add-your-company-branding) this for How-to do stuff
Alternatively, you can also try [Alternative CSS URL](https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/Publishing-Infrastructure-Alternate-CSS-URL.htm)

All the best!

Comment: Thanks man, looks good! Sadly, I do not have permission to enter the "Themes" section